# Как написать функцию для изменения контента в другом блоке по клике на элемент выпадающего списка (Vue.js)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Имеется следующий код:

```
export default {
name: 'HowToGet',
template: `
<section class="how-to-get" id="how-to-get">
<div class="container">
    <h3 class=" h3 how-to-get__head">Как добраться</h3>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-5">
            <div class="how-to-get__dropdown-wrap">
                <div class="how-to-get__dropdown-title">Откуда выезжаете?</div>
                <div class="dropdown-button dropdown">
                    <button class="dropdown-button__button button dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropbutton1" 
                    data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" data-display="static">Москва</button>
                    <div id="city-dropdown" class="dropdown-button__wrap dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropbutton1">
                         <a class="dropdown-button__item dropdown-item" data-transport=""
                         href="javascript:void(0)" v-for="city in cities" @click="changeMap">{{ city.name }}</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-7">
            <div class="how-to-get__dropdown-wrap how-to-get__dropdown-wrap_right">
                <div class="how-to-get__dropdown-title">На чем выезжаете?</div>
                <div class="dropdown-button dropdown">
                    <button class="dropdown-button__button button dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropbutton2" 
                    data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" data-display="static">Бесплатный трансфер</button>
                    <div v-for="city in cities" id="transport-dropdown" class="dropdown-button__wrap dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropbutton2">
                        <a v-for="transport in city.transport" class="dropdown-button__item dropdown-item" 
                        :data-map-id="transport.dataMapId" href="javascript:void(0)">{{ transport.name }}</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="how-to-get-tab">
        <nav class="tab-switch nav">
            <a class="tab-switch__link nav-link active" data-template="#map_" href="#map_139" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">Карта</a>
            <a class="tab-switch__link nav-link" data-template="#route_" href="#route_139" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">Описание маршрута</a>
        </nav>
        <div class="tab-content">
             <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="map_139" role="tabpanel">
                <div class="how-to-get__map-wrap">
                   <div v-for="city in cities" class="how-to-get__map-item">
                      <iframe v-for="transport in city.transport" :src="transport.mapLink" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>                        
                   </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="route_139" role="tabpanel">
               <div class="how-to-get__route-wrap">
                  <div class="how-to-get__route-head">Бесплатный трансфер из Москвы 8 и 9 июня</div>
                  <div class="how-to-get__route-text">Для участников и сопровождающих Sport-Marafon Trail организован 8 и 9 июня 2019 г. 
                  трансфер из Москвы прямиком до Никола-Ленивца. Стоимость трансфера в три раза ниже самостоятельной поездки — 700 рублей. 
                    В эту стоимость входит отправление из Москвы и дорога обратно из Никола-Ленивца в Москву. 
                    Отправление автобусов будет происходить от метро Тропарево в субботу 8 июня в 10:00 и в воскресенье 9 июня в 5:00. 
                    Время в дороге займет около 4 часов. Зарегистрироваться на трансфер возможно на странице регистрации</div>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
`,
data() {
    return {
        cities: [
            {
                name:'Москва',
                cityId: '77',
                transport: [
                    {
                        name: 'Бесплатный трансфер',
                        dataMapId: '139',
                        mapLink: 'https://yandex.ru/map-widget/v1/-/CCq9mTkq'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Общественный транспорт',
                        dataMapId: '141',
                        mapLink: 'https://yandex.ru/map-widget/v1/-/CCq9F-IK'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                name:'Калуга',
                cityId: '40',
                transport: [
                    {
                        name: 'Бесплатный трансфер',
                        dataMapId: '140',
                        mapLink: 'https://yandex.ru/map-widget/v1/-/CCq9JT-K'
                    }
                ]

            }
        ]
    }
},
methods: {
    changeMap() {

    }
  },
};
```

Как написать функцию для изменения карты при клике на `<a class="dropdown-button__item dropdown-item" ></a>`? То есть, например, кликаем на Москву – появляется карта, соответствующая Москве, кликаем на Калугу – появляется карта, соответствующая Калуге.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил так:

```
export default {
name: 'HowToGet',
template: `
<section class="how-to-get" id="how-to-get">
<div class="container">
    <h3 class=" h3 how-to-get__head">Как добраться</h3>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-5">
            <div class="how-to-get__dropdown-wrap">
                <div class="how-to-get__dropdown-title">Откуда выезжаете?</div>
                <div class="dropdown-button dropdown">
                    <button class="dropdown-button__button button dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropbutton1" 
                    data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" data-display="static">Москва</button>
                    <div id="city-dropdown" class="dropdown-button__wrap dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropbutton1">
                         <a class="dropdown-button__item dropdown-item" data-transport=""
                         href="javascript:void(0)" 
                         v-for="city in cities"
                         @click="selectedCity = city.name"
                         >{{ city.name }}</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-7">
            <div class="how-to-get__dropdown-wrap how-to-get__dropdown-wrap_right">
                <div class="how-to-get__dropdown-title">На чем выезжаете?</div>
                <div class="dropdown-button dropdown">
                    <button class="dropdown-button__button button dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropbutton2" 
                    data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" data-display="static">Бесплатный трансфер</button>
                    <div v-for="city in cities" id="transport-dropdown" class="dropdown-button__wrap dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropbutton2">
                        <a v-for="transport in city.transport" class="dropdown-button__item dropdown-item" 
                        :data-map-id="transport.dataMapId" href="javascript:void(0)">{{ transport.name }}</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="how-to-get-tab">
        <nav class="tab-switch nav">
            <a class="tab-switch__link nav-link active" data-template="#map_" href="#map_139" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">Карта</a>
            <a class="tab-switch__link nav-link" data-template="#route_" href="#route_139" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">Описание маршрута</a>
        </nav>
        <div class="tab-content">
             <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="map_139" role="tabpanel">
                <div class="how-to-get__map-wrap" v-if="maps">
                  <iframe v-for="map in maps" :src="map.mapLink" frameborder="0" 
                  allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="route_139" role="tabpanel">
               <div class="how-to-get__route-wrap">
                  <div class="how-to-get__route-head">Бесплатный трансфер из Москвы 8 и 9 июня</div>
                  <div class="how-to-get__route-text">Для участников и сопровождающих Sport-Marafon Trail организован 8 и 9 июня 2019 г. 
                  трансфер из Москвы прямиком до Никола-Ленивца. Стоимость трансфера в три раза ниже самостоятельной поездки — 700 рублей. 
                    В эту стоимость входит отправление из Москвы и дорога обратно из Никола-Ленивца в Москву. 
                    Отправление автобусов будет происходить от метро Тропарево в субботу 8 июня в 10:00 и в воскресенье 9 июня в 5:00. 
                    Время в дороге займет около 4 часов. Зарегистрироваться на трансфер возможно на странице регистрации</div>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
`,
data() {
    return {
        cities: [
            {
                name:'Москва',
                cityId: '77',
                transport: [
                    {
                        name: 'Бесплатный трансфер',
                        dataMapId: '139',
                        mapLink: 'https://yandex.ru/map-widget/v1/-/CCq9mTkq'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Общественный транспорт',
                        dataMapId: '141',
                        mapLink: 'https://yandex.ru/map-widget/v1/-/CCq9F-IK'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                name:'Калуга',
                cityId: '40',
                transport: [
                    {
                        name: 'Бесплатный трансфер',
                        dataMapId: '140',
                        mapLink: 'https://yandex.ru/map-widget/v1/-/CCq9JT-K'
                    }
                ],
              selectedCity: ''
            }
        ]
    }
},
computed: {
    maps() {
        return (this.cities.find(n => n.name === this.selectedCity) || {}).transport;
    }
},
```

То есть добавляю свойство `selectedCity` в `data` и даю возможность пользователю устанавливать его значение, достаю карты по значению selectedCity. Если город выбран и карты существуют, то они отрисовываются